# Why does the submanifold S exists?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I'm working through some lecture notes Which say the following:

> Let $M$ be a manifold wich is provided with an action of Lie group $G$. Fix $x \in M$  and let $a_x: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow T_xM $ be the infinitesimal action at $x$. Choose a submanifold $S$ of $M$ containing $x$ such that
> $$a_x(\mathfrak{g}) \oplus T_xS = T_xM. $$

My question is why does the submanifold $S$ with the property above exists ?

Ps: this is a screenshot from which I get my question:
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: The existence of $S$ is not proven in, like, the next sentence of the notes or something? Maybe at the end of the current proof (or whatever context this is taken from)? That's where I might put it.

Comment: @Arthur, I've edited my question, hopefully it is clearer now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a general result which is not too difficult to prove. Throughout, let $M$ be a smooth manifold:

> **lemma**: For any linear subspace $V\subseteq T_xM$, there is an embedded submanifold $S\subseteq M$ such that $T_xS=V$.
>
> **proof**: Choose a coordinate ball $\varphi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ centered around $x$. In the canonical basis induced by $\varphi$, $V$ can be identified with a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n\cong T_xM$. Let $S$ be the preimage of the same linear subspace by $\varphi$. Composing $\varphi$ with a rotation will yield a slice chart for $S$, so it is an embedded submanifold.

In your case, $a_{x_0}(\mathfrak{g})$ is a linear subspace of $T_{x_0}M$, so we can find complimentary subspace $V\subset T_{x_0}M$ such that $T_{x_0}M\cong a_{x_0}(\mathfrak{g})\oplus V$, and by the previous lemma $V=T_{x_0}S$ for some embedded submanifold $S$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kajelad for your answer! I have a question in the proof, i don't understand the last sentence: "composing $\varphi$ with a rotation will yield a slice chart for S ".   Could you please elaborate further in this point please ?

Comment: @asma By slice chart, I mean a chart $\sigma:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $U\cap S=\sigma^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^k\times\{0\}^{n-k})$. These are often used as a definition of embedded submanifolds. The chart $\varphi$ isn't a slice chart, but we can rotate any $k$-dimensional subspace onto the subspace spanned by the first $k$ coordinates.

Comment: Ok thank you so much @Kajelad for your help!